# Один post обработчик для нескольких форм. Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, post, html-form

Здравствуйте, подскажите как приучить код к нескольким формам на странице.

Обработчик:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* Следующий код выполняется только после загрузки DOM */

    /* Данный флаг предотвращает отправку нескольких комментариев: */
    var working = false;

    /* Ловим событие отправки формы: */
    $('#addCommentForm').submit(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();
        if(working) return false;

        working = true;
        $('#submit').val('Занято...');
        $('span.error').remove();

        /* Отправляем поля формы в comment.php: */
        $.post('comment.php',$(this).serialize(),function(msg){

            working = false;
            $('#submit').val('Отправить');

            if(msg.status){

                /* 
                /   Если вставка была успешной, добавляем комментарий 
                /   ниже последнего на странице с эффектом slideDown
                /*/

                $(msg.html).hide().insertBefore('#addCommentContainer').slideDown();
                $('#body').val('');
            }
            else {

                /*
                /   Если есть ошибки, проходим циклом по объекту
                /   msg.errors и выводим их на страницу
                /*/

                $.each(msg.errors,function(k,v){
                    $('label[for='+k+']').append(''+v+'');
                });
            }
        },'json');

    });

});
```

Форма:

```
<div id="addCommentContainer">
<p>Добавить комментарий</p>
<form id="addCommentForm" method="post" action="">
<div>
<label for="name">Имя</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" />

<label for="email">Email</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" />

<label for="url">Вебсайт (не обязательно)</label>
<input type="text" name="url" id="url" />

<label for="body">Содержание комментария</label>
<textarea name="body" id="body" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>

<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Отправить" />
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

Нужно чтобы было несколько таких форм на странице и обработчик мог работать с ними по отдельности. Т.е определял с какой формы именно отправлен post, обрабатывал данные и писал ответ.
А в данный момент он работает только с одной.

Можно по идее поменять на id="addCommentForm" на class="addCommentForm" и привешать на каждую форму разный id... Но я не знаю, как потом его выловить через jquery. :(

Comment: вы можете использовать класс, а не id что бы прикрепить обработчик.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman ну да, я могу вместо #addCommentContainer использовать .addCommentContainer ... А толку то?

Comment: если вы пометите формы этим классом, то обработчик будет добавлен к каждой

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Не пойму... если id="addCommentForm" class="CommentForm" - это же ничего не изменит?!  
Классы то тоже одинаковые получатся у всех... и будет также всегда вставляться в самую первую из них... а надо чтобы в ту из которой отправили.

Comment: тогда вам следует описать желаемое поведение в вопросе. так как сейчас это не отражено в нем.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Мне нужно чтобы было несколько форм таких на странице и обработчик мог работать с ними про отдельности.

Comment: Дополняйте ваш вопрос согласно [рекомендациям по ведению дискуссий на Stack Overflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691/6), вместо публикации комментариев.

Answer (score 1):

Используй класс вместо id, тогда твой обработчик привяжется ко всем формам, а не первой найденной по id.

Answer (score 0):

Можно повешать класс на форму и будем обращаться к классу

```
$('.addCommentForm').submit(function(e){...
```

или просто обрабатывать ВСЕ формы

```
$('form').submit(function(e){...
```

как вам больше нравится...

а потом определять id формы и передавать его в пост

```
$id = $(this).attr("id");
```

или у каждой формы сделать хиден поле в котором будет указан тип формы. В посте будем получать тип и в зависимости от типа по разному обрабатывать